# Swift 同じViewController内にPickerViewを2つ別の内容で配置

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

アプリ開発初心者です。

PickerViewを同じ画面内に二つ配置し、
それぞれ別の値を保持し、ラベルに出力しようと思っているのですが、
以下のコードで実行すると、二つとも同じ値で表示されてしまいます。
何か解決はありますでしょうか？

回答、よろしくお願い致します。

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickerview1: UIPickerView!
var list: [[String]] = [
    ["容量"],
    ["30"],
    ["ml"]
]

@IBOutlet weak var pickerview2: UIPickerView!
var list2: [[String]] = [
    ["0"],
    ["時"],
    ["0"],
    ["分"]
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    for a in 31...150  {
        var b : String = ""
        b = String(a)
        list[1].append(b)
    }

    for c in 1...23 {
        var d : String = ""
        d = String(c)
        list2[0].append(d)
    }

    for e in 1...59 {
        var f : String = ""
        f = String(e)
        list2[2].append(f)
    }

    pickerview1.dataSource = self
    pickerview1.delegate = self

    pickerview2.dataSource = self
    pickerview2.delegate = self
}

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!    

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerview1: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return list.count
}

func pickerView(pickerview1: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return list[component].count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.width/CGFloat(list.count), 44))
    //label.textColor = colorPattern.main()
    label.text = list[component][row] as String
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return label
}

@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView1(pickerview2: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return list2.count
}

func pickerView2(pickerview3: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return list2[component].count
}

func pickerView2(pickerView2: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
    let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView2.frame.width/CGFloat(list2.count), 44))
    //label.textColor = colorPattern.main()
    label2.text = list2[component][row] as String
    label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return label2
}

func pickerView(pickerview1: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    label1.text =  "容量" + list[component][row] + "ml"    
}

func pickerView2(pickerview3: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    label2.text =  "時間" + list2[component][row]
}
```

Comment: 「解決」といわれても……。「やはり、自分のプログラムがどこか間違ってるんだろうなあ」という意識が、必要ではないかと思いますよ。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、つぎのふたつのリファレンスを読みましょう。

[UIPickerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/)
[UIPickerViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)UIPickerViewDataSource)

`UIPickerView`からDelegate（委託）で送られてくるメソッドは、このふたつのリファレンスに載っているものですべてです。ほかのメソッドが送られることはありません。
たとえば、

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView1(pickerview2: UIPickerView) -> Int
func pickerView2(pickerview3: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
func pickerView2(pickerView2: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
```

これらのメソッドが送られてくることはけっしてないので、これらのメソッドを実装しても、無意味です。

`pickerview1`も`pickerview2`もおなじDelegate（Datasource）メソッドを送ってきます。この点に、あなたの理解がなかったら、あるいはまちがった理解をしていたなら、正しい理解に改めてください。
同じメソッドを送ってくるのですから、送り主によって条件分岐して、適切な処理をそれぞれに行わなければいけません。
一例を示します。

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
if pickerView == pickerview1 {
    return list.count
} else {
    return list2.count 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StoryboardでPickerViewのIDをそれぞれ別々に指定しておいて、コード内では
コールバックメソッドを分けるのではなく、一つのコールバックメソッドで引数
に入ってくるPickerViewのIDを見て処理を分岐させる必要があると思います。